# Cannot cover ContentDistribution trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I have a trigger

```
trigger ContentDistributionAfterInsert on ContentDistribution (after insert) {
    system.debug('test');
    for(ContentDistribution cd : trigger.new)
    {
        ContentMethods.updateurl1(cd.id); 
    }
}
```

however, test class executes successfully

```
        ContentVersion newVersion = new ContentVersion();
        newVersion.Title = 'my version title';
        newVersion.pathOnClient = 'url';
        newVersion.VersionData=blob.valueof('test data');
        insert newVersion;

        ContentDistribution distribution = new ContentDistribution();
        distribution.Name = newVersion.title + ' ' +  Date.today();
        distribution.ContentVersionId = newVersion.Id;
        distribution.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit = false;
        distribution.PreferencesNotifyRndtnComplete = false;
        insert distribution;
```

The trigger never fires in the test but works when used in the org.

Test class coverage screenshot
[image: Test class coverage screenshot]

If the test class had accessed the trigger, atleast the fist line would have been covered

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that your trigger is supposed to be fire before and after an insert. It must be only one of these. Before OR after. Here's the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) to help you with that.

Comment: @MartinLezer I've changed to after insert only, removing the before insert. Yet the trigger is not covered

Comment: @AdrianLarson I am inserting it only in my test class and the trigger just updates another object

Answer (score 1):

Remove the empty `catch` block. Never, ever, do that to yourself or your fellow developers. It will just silently swallow errors. Specifically, the one you are trying to find/solve right now. You basically forced your test to lie to you about whether it passes or fails with this pattern:

```
try
{
    insert distribution;
}
catch (DmlException d)
{
    // good luck figuring out what went wrong!
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Adrian, 
but the test runs successfully and the trigger is not covered

Comment: Can you edit your post to make it more clear why you think the trigger is not being called?

Comment: Did you check the Active checkbox on top of the trigger page?

Comment: I used to do the same mistake, Silencing the errors to let code deploy successfully. Had to stay awake whole night to solve a blunder. Never did that again

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Yeah once you learn that lesson the hard way once...it's more than enough. I've had some very long and confusing debug sessions myself that ended down that rabbit hole.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: To reiterate Martin's question, can you please verify the trigger is active?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes the trigger is active because, when I comment-out the code inside, my functionality fails.